# One query with joins not directly connected with themself

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I want to fetch complex client data using one query. I've build one sql query, but it is a little bit slow.

```
select * from client cli
join contract con on cli.id = con.client_id
join payment pay on con.id = pay.contract_id
join car on cli.id = car.client_id
join address adr on cli.id = adr.client_id
where cli.id in (x, y, z) //up to 1000 clients
```

as you can see entity address/car/contract are jointed directly to client but payments are joined to contracts and then to client.

I wonder if this query can be somehow boosted, in case for example when we have structure

```
  client 
      contract
          payment1
          payment2
          payment3
```

first part of query

```
select * from client cli
join contract con on cli.id = con.client_id
join payment pay on con.id = pay.contract_id
```

generate result of

```
 client contract payment1
 client contract payment2
 client contract payment3
```

and then we have

```
join car on cli.id = car.client_id
```

it means that this join will be run 3 times ? Even though in those 3 records there is only one client id ?

Maybe I should split my query to those joined directly and those with additonal joins

first query

```
select * from client cli
join contract con on cli.id = con.client_id
join payment pay on con.id = pay.contract_id
```

second query

```
select * from client cli
join car on cli.id = car.client_id
join address adr on cli.id = adr.client_id
```

but then I need to merge them manually and it makes harder to understand whole concept. Maybe I should place contract join in subselect or I should use common table expression ?

Comment: There is no relationship between cars and payments, so your goal of a single query doesn't make much sense. Your resultset should represent a real set of "something" and your current attempt simply "jams" these two different aspects of a client in rows. Seems you may need to revisit this approach and handle it differently depending on who/what is consuming this information.

Comment: As I said I need to update whole client data. So I need all of this data at this point. I can make 5 different queries for each domain, but then I will lose a lot of time on manual merging into one result. So the question is do I can boost somehow this query.  At the beggining I though that spliting it to 2+ queries do not make differences in efficienty for database engine optimizer, but I am new with sql server.

Comment: If you need payment in your query results, and if you need all in one table, then there is no way other than repeating data for each payment.